# CSS Aspect Ratio in flexbox container

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to make a `div` that fills all available height of its parent, while maintaining a 16/9 aspect ratio. However, it's filling the width and thus not keeping the aspect ratio I've set. Any advice on how to fix this?

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="problem"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.problem {
  height: 200px;
}
.inner {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background-color: blue;
}

html,body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cqhtb8sw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to flexbox, you can add this in your inner styles:

```
  height:100%;
  width: min-content;
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!

I also ended up adding `margin: 0 auto` to make it center and not overflow horizontally.

Comment: I think `align-self: center` should also work for the horizontal centering, if you want to keep using flex box properties